# For primes sufficiently large, must digit products be zero?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\{P_n\}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ be the sequence prime numbers such that $P_1=2, P_2=3\dots$.

Define a new sequence $\{M_n\}$,  $n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $M_n=$Product of the digits of the $nth$ prime in its decimal representation.

Now the question is: Does there exist an $N\in  \mathbb{N}$, such that $M_n=0$ $  \forall n\geq N$ ?

Comment: This is equivalent to asking there exist a minimum $n$ such that every prime after that contains either a 2,4,6,8 and a 5 in its decimal representation

Comment: Ohi misread the quesiton. I thought it was asking if there exists a point such that the last digit is always 0. (

Comment: "at least one 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 And a 5" is what i meant to say to be precise (noting that the products of these digits is 0).

Comment: Look at http://oeis.org/A038618 In particular: "Maynard proves that this sequence is infinite"

Comment: If you look at other bases, the question is not settled. For example, with binary, the question is equivalent to whether there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, and closely related to whether there are infinitely many even perfect numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  [This 2016 paper by James Maynard](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01041)  says that there are infinitely many primes not containing the digit $0$.  So $M_n \gt 0$ infinitely often.

Comment: That is astonishing. Not that it's true, but that somebody was able to prove it.